# Visual Basic 9.0 does not support this kind of lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I get this error **"Visual Basic 9.0 does not support this kind of lambda expression"** here " ExecuteWithinTransaction(**Sub**(con, trans) InsertA("Al", con, trans))" when i hover over the **Sub**

I am new to lambda expressions. Any help appreciated. I am using VS 2010 and .NET 3.5.

```vb
Sub Main() 
    ExecuteWithinTransaction(Sub(con, trans) InsertA("Al", con, trans))
    ExecuteWithinTransaction(Sub(con, trans) InsertB("Bert", con, trans))

    ExecuteWithinTransaction(Sub(con, trans)
                                 InsertA("Albert", con, trans)
                                 InsertB("Einstein", con, trans)
                             End Sub)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Executes an action within a transaction. handles connection and transaction management
''' </summary>
''' <param name="action">The action to be executed</param>
Sub ExecuteWithinTransaction(ByVal action As Action(Of SqlConnection, SqlTransaction))
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("CONNECTIONSTRING")

    connection.Open()
    Try
        Dim transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()

        Try
            action(connection, transaction)
            transaction.Commit()
        Catch ex As Exception
            transaction.Rollback()
            Throw 'rethrow exception preserving original stacktrace
        End Try
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try 
End Sub

Sub InsertA(ByVal name As String, ByVal connection As SqlConnection, ByVal transaction As SqlTransaction)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO XXX (Name) VALUES (@NAME)", connection, transaction)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub

Sub InsertB(ByVal name As String, ByVal connection As SqlConnection, ByVal transaction As SqlTransaction)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO YYY (Name) VALUES (@NAME)", connection, transaction)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you use .NET 3.5 with VS 2010?

Comment: @TimSchmelter  There are different developers working on the same project and everyone does not have VS 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Statement lambdas (`Sub`s) are supported in VB.NET 2012+.</s>

VB.NET 2010 only supports function lambdas (`Function`s).

See Ric's comments below for the answer.

Workaround if changing FW version is not possible: Write little helper subs in the ordinary, non-lambda form, and then pass them as delegates to `ExecuteWithinTransaction`.

So you would have

```
private sub Lambda1 (con as SqlConnection, tran as SqlTransaction)
  InsertA("Al", con, tran)
end sub

private sub Lambda2 (con as SqlConnection, tran as SqlTransaction)
  InsertB("Bert", con, tran)
end sub

private sub Lambda3 (con as SqlConnection, tran as SqlTransaction)
  InsertA("Albert", con, tran)
  InsertB("Einstein", con, tran)
end sub
```

And then

```
ExecuteWithinTransaction (AddressOf Lambda1)
ExecuteWithinTransaction (AddressOf Lambda2)
ExecuteWithinTransaction (AddressOf Lambda3)
```

Comment: Could you please give a code sample according to the above Code..I have no idea how to write the helper sub and pass the delegate.

Comment: actually 2010 does support both those type of lambda expressions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Ric Looks like I mistook 2010 features for 2008 features.

Comment: @Ric Nope , that's not the reason.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for the solution. It worked. A tiny question , what if the subs `InsertA` and `InsertB` are in a separate class. I mean in the business logic layer and i have to call this subs from any random aspx.vb page?

Comment: @Monodeep Then either make your lambdas accept one more parameter to hold an instance of that class, or create an instance of that class inside the lambda.

Comment: how do you pass in the variables to "Lambda1" when the "Albert"-string is not a constant without introducing new fields (which would mimic the Closure in a minimalistic way)?

Comment: @Monodeep By adding more parameters. You already have `con` and `tran`, add more.

Comment: Why did i ask that?? My Bad